# Importing an image and drawing a square on it

Tags: python, opencv, draw

I'm trying to import an Image and draw a square, like that:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

relpath='C:/Users/mydesktop/trainedModels/CKcollect/1/'
img=image.load_img(relpath+'S010_004_00000014.png')
plt.imshow(img)
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)
plt.imshow(img)
```

and I get this error message:

```
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Comment: use `img = cv2.imread(relpath+'S010_004_00000014.png')` to read image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cv2.imread(PATH)` instead of `image.load_img(PATH)` if it still doesn't work make sure to use the full path to the image

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv2.imread()` method it takes two argument (img, flag). second argument is optional, you can just pass your image and in second argument you can pass (-1, 0, 1).

-1 or cv2.IMREAD_COLOR : Color, Default

0 or cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : Grayscale

1 or cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED : alpha channel